# How do I get information ("tier","rank","leaguePoints") from only the section of json with "RANKED_SOLO_5x5" and not "RANKED_FLEX_SR"

Tags: javascript, json

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtJ4J.png)

```
[
  {
    leagueId: "51f35167-0e62-41b0-bb5d-8ec376e754d7",
    queueType: "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
    tier: "GOLD",
    rank: "II",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 1,
    wins: 7,
    losses: 5,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
  {
    leagueId: "0e4412d1-81c2-4839-9045-c0cb556ebdcb",
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    tier: "PLATINUM",
    rank: "III",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 75,
    wins: 222,
    losses: 205,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
];
```

```
function RANKFIND(league_ign) {
var tempign = "Impermanencë"
var apirequest1 = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"
var apirequest2 = "?api_key={KEYVALUE}"
var idapirequest = (apirequest1 + tempign + apirequest2)
Logger.log(idapirequest);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(idapirequest);
var content = response.getContentText();
Logger.log(content)
var json = JSON.parse(content)
var id = json["id"]
Logger.log(id);

var tempid = "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg"
var apirequest3 = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/"
var apirequest4 = "?api_key={KEYVALUE}"
var apirequestfull = (apirequest3 + id + apirequest4)
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apirequestfull);
var content = response.getContentText();
var json2 = JSON.parse(content)
Logger.log(json2);
var json3 = json2[0]
var tier = json3["tier"];
var rank = json3["rank"];
var league_points = json3["leaguePoints"];
var full_rank = (tier+ "," + rank + " " + league_points + "lp")
Logger.log(full_rank)
return full_rank
}
```

Comment: Please add some information in the body of the question, not just the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index of an object in arr and you know it won't change then you can use `index` to get the object and then destructure it

```
const { tier, rank, leaguePoints } = arr[1];
console.log(tier, rank, leaguePoints);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    leagueId: "51f35167-0e62-41b0-bb5d-8ec376e754d7",
    queueType: "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
    tier: "GOLD",
    rank: "II",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 1,
    wins: 7,
    losses: 5,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
  {
    leagueId: "0e4412d1-81c2-4839-9045-c0cb556ebdcb",
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    tier: "PLATINUM",
    rank: "III",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 75,
    wins: 222,
    losses: 205,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
];

const { tier, rank, leaguePoints } = arr[1];
console.log(tier, rank, leaguePoints);
```

else you need to use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the element and then destructure.

```
const obj = arr.find((o) => o.queueType === "RANKED_SOLO_5x5");
const { tier, rank, leaguePoints } = obj;
console.log(tier, rank, leaguePoints);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    leagueId: "51f35167-0e62-41b0-bb5d-8ec376e754d7",
    queueType: "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
    tier: "GOLD",
    rank: "II",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 1,
    wins: 7,
    losses: 5,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
  {
    leagueId: "0e4412d1-81c2-4839-9045-c0cb556ebdcb",
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    tier: "PLATINUM",
    rank: "III",
    summonerId: "YZ9wH1Bldkndu5YnBb9cYn5corkcU_rDCVsVEaHDttelCVg",
    summonerName: "Impermanencë",
    leaguePoints: 75,
    wins: 222,
    losses: 205,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: false,
    hotStreak: false,
  },
];

const obj = arr.find((o) => o.queueType === "RANKED_SOLO_5x5");
const { tier, rank, leaguePoints } = obj;
console.log(tier, rank, leaguePoints);
```